# How to display "/oauth/token" endpoint on swagger-ui?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-ui

My project use spring cloud oauth to authenticate user with "/oauth/token" endpoint, but i can't find any way to display this api operation on swagger ui. What should I do?

Swagger Configuration:

```
@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("all").select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.demo.userservice.api.controller"))
            .paths(regex("/api.*"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(metaInfo());
}



private ApiInfo metaInfo() {

    ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
            "Spring Boot Swagger USERSERVICE API",
            "Spring Boot Swagger USERSERVICE API",
            "1.0",
            "Terms of Service",
            new Contact("userservice", "",
                    ""),
            "Apache License Version 2.0",
            "https://www.apache.org/licesen.html", new ArrayList<VendorExtension>()
    );

    return apiInfo;
}


}
```

Comment: Add your swagger configuration

Comment: Added the same @Eklavya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is open all endpoint to show `oauth/token` endpoint this way

```
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
.paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().pathMapping("/")
```

Or

If you want to show only desired path like `/api/.*` then you can modify the endpoint of oauth using this

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class EndPointModificationConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {    

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
            endpoints
                .pathMapping("/oauth/token", "/api/oauth/token");
        }
}
```

And use this for get all api

```
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
```

Comment: Thanks.It's now showing on swagger-ui but I am not getting how to send a request for OAuth token  as parameters are different  from what we send while hitting from postman. Is there any way to modify those also?

Comment: May be not. It's auto-generarated as oauth design in theirs api

Comment: And I wonder why parameters are different , may be their are many parameters.

Comment: It's only showing two parameters one is for  String and another takes the Object as a value.

Comment: Yes only two parameter name and parameters, you  can send `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data

Comment: okay. I got your point but I want to expose this API on swagger so that my frontend team members can login by filling their credentials in different fields like they can do using postman.

Comment: I don't know how you modify your endpoint but you can't get those flexibility that you get in postman. It's autogenerated.

Comment: I have found something on google which is using ApiListingScannerPlugin interface we can achieve this. but In this, I'm not getting how to send my clientId and secret.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213026/discussion-between-eklavya-and-bushra-saifi).